# memory leak worksheetfunction excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, memory-leaks, excel-2016

I've have a sub-routine that loops through calculations many times.  Recently in Excel 2016 I've started running out of memory.

The following demonstration code is OK in 2010, 2013, even 2016 for Mac, but in 2016 for windows, it accumulates about 500MB in the memory that is not released until it quits Excel.  Not sure how long 2016 has been behaving like this; just started noticing it yesterday.

It seems to be the worksheet function that is causing the leak.  I use a number of worksheet functions in my real loop.  Any ideas how to flush this?

```
Sub MemTest()

iend = 1000000

For i = 1 To iend

    deg2rad = Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi / 180

    deg2rad = Empty

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you see these 500M ? (is it swap, process memory , etc ) ?

Comment: Just watch the task manager and see the memory usage fill up.  Once Excel gets to about 1.4GB it will start crashing.  After this routine is run 2-3 times it is crashed.  Can you repeat this experiment and see the same behaviour?

Comment: no, you try the example bellow and test if it cause memory leak, if your example is the real example that cause the memory leak.

Comment: when you say no, do you mean you ran the simple demonstration loop in excel 2016, and did not get persistent memory allocation (leak)?  I tried it on 2 machines with excel 2016 and got the problem on both. The version you posted below does not cause a leak.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing with an update about the memory leak in excel 2016.
Seems the issue was not to do with my code at all.  And thanks to the person who pointed out that focusing on the worksheetfunction was antipattern.

I first noticed the memory leak in late December.  Over Xmas, others have posted similar findings in other threads on this forum, and on others, and microsoft has answered that it is a bug in excel 2016 that does not release the memory properly.  There is a fix in the link that follows, and hopefully an update to fix it properly soon.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-excel/excel-2016-macro-crashes-sometimes-gibes-an-out-of/37a7df04-9d1b-4b6b-b107-e8d0971e324e?auth=1

Answer (score 2):

The fix is out! It's in build 16.0.6366.2062, which started rolling out on 1/25/16. If you don't have the update yet, go to File > Account > Update Options > Update Now.

Thanks for your patience.

Anneliese from the Office Team.

Answer (score 1):

Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi is a constant so define as constant at the begging of code.Then  deg2rad = Empty is pointless, because reaffectation.

```
Sub MemTest()
iend = 1000000
const cPI = application.WorksheetFunction.Pi 'don't call it iend time
For i = 1 To iend

    deg2rad = cPI / 180 'or deg2rad = 3.14159265358979 /180

Next i

End Sub
```

Sometime you should ease the processor with a "Sleep" or "wait" doevents

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I know it is pointless to do this calculation in the loop.  I use other trig functions such as Asin in my real loop.  I just used the Pi example to show the behaviour.  I don't think I can remove all the worksheet functions from my code, so I want to know how to correct the memory leak.

Comment: I think loops ask for object creation too fast for system to release memory. your example is a kind of antipattern.

Comment: I think you sould let your loops breathe, Excel dont like loops without easing processor and object destruction/creation, that you obtain adding a  sleep.

Comment: I am familiar with the behaviour where excel stops responding during long loops, although I cannot see in the task manager that this is due to memory leak at all.  In my application, I make use of progress bars, or application.statusbar and DoEvents to avoid this issue.  I have these in the loop with the memory leak also.  Calling these DoEvents more often does not fix the leak.